# Oracle - object order - how does it work?

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

Oracle doc says as follows: "As with map methods, an order method, if one is defined, is called automatically whenever two objects of that type need to be compared."

So I assume it will sort when using 'order by' clausule.

Lets say, I have following object:

```
create or replace type height as object
(
    val number,

    constructor function height return self as result,
    constructor function height (val number) return self as result,

    order member function compare (other height) RETURN INTEGER 
);
```

and its body implementation:

```
create or replace type body height is
    constructor function height return self as result is
         begin
            self.val := null;
         end;

    constructor function height (val number) return self as result is
         begin
            self.val := val;
            return;
         end; 

    order member function compare (other height) return integer is
        begin
            if self.val > self.val then return 1;
            elsif self.val < self.val then return -1;
            else return 0;
            end if;
        end;
end;
```

Then my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    name varchar2(50),
    height height
);
```

And some records ...

```
insert into people values ('Foo', height(150));
insert into people values ('Bar', height(130));
insert into people valueS ('Baz', height(180));
```

Then I want to sort it:

```
select p.height.val from people p order by height ASC;
select p.height.val from people p order by height DESC;
```

But result is the same for 2 queries, no matter if order is asc or desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In turned out to be a simple mistake... 
Implementation of compare function compares `self` with `self` instead with `other`.

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with your code and found a solution.

The solution that works looks like this

I have added a second compare function with two parameters

```
create or replace type height as object
(
    val number,

    constructor function height return self as result,
    constructor function height (val number) return self as result,

    order member function compare2 (other height) return integer,
    member function compare (o1 height,o2 height) return integer
);
/
```

```
create or replace type body height is
    constructor function height return self as result is
         begin
            self.val := null;
         end;

    constructor function height (val number) return self as result is
         begin
            self.val := val;
            return;
         end; 

    order member function compare2 (other height) return integer is
       begin
            RETURN compare(SELF,other);
        end;
     member function compare (o1 height,o2 height) return integer is
        begin
          if o1.val > o2.val then return 1;
            elsif o1.val < o2.val then return -1;
            else return 0;
            end if;
        end;    

end;
/
```

> ```
> select p.height.val from people p order by height ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> | HEIGHT.VAL |
> | ---------: |
> |        130 |
> |        150 |
> |        180 |
> ```

> ```
> select p.height.val from people p order by height DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> | HEIGHT.VAL |
> | ---------: |
> |        180 |
> |        150 |
> |        130 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a613606dfd38a2b577d3a5e6c53105ee)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me to find out what is wrong with my code... It turned out that in compare function I compared self with self... (if self.val > self.val then return 1) instead self with other. Here is corrected code https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e891c1584a73dbec5fc506e9a889e32